# Booting directly in debian linux without giving username and password

Tags: debian, login

I would like to skip the username and password prompt at boot-up from debian linux. I want to boot directly to the system without giving username and password.

Comment: I assume you mean login and not boot up right? If you have a password set on boot, you will need to change it in your BIOS.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume you mean the console, as opposed to GNOME or KDE or some such, in which case: http://littlesvr.ca/linux-stuff/articles/autologinconsole/autologinconsole.php

This is a very easy problem to search for on the web: "linux auto login".